# Convert c# Datetime to input[type=date]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

all i want is to convert 07.03.2014 to 2014-03-07, `dd.mm.yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` in asp.net MVC controller ;) Thank you.

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Please only tag your question with a specific version number if your question is actually dependent on the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ToString()` method on a DateTime object to get the format you want.

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime(2014,03,07);
string newDateFormatted= dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If you want to load your date time object from a string, You may try using [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
or `DateTime.ParseExtract` or `TryParse`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good list of format specifiers you can use with `ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

I used to create a Editor Template to work with `DataTime & Nullable<DateTime>` like below

**Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomDateTime.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    String modelValue = "";
    var dateFormat =
             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;


    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            if (ViewData["_displayFormat"] != null)
            {
             var format=(string)ViewData["_displayFormat"];
              modelValue = Model.Value.ToString(format)

            } 
            else{
            modelValue = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}

    @Html.TextBox("", modelValue)
```

In View

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, "CustomDateTime", 
                  new { _displayFormat= "yyyy-MM-dd"})
```

Comment: Super useful, thanks. Small thing: I noticed dateFormat is declared on line 4 but not used at all?

Answer (score 0):

What we do for the Angular App, we use 2 params on backend
(**DateTime Born** for ORM and ****string** bornDate** as transport param in transport class)

C# (backend to frontend as string)

```
bornDate = Born.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**bornDate string** works with Angular model data binding with HTML5 input "date" type.

Then we pass modified string back to backend where we parse it in C#.

C# (frontend to backend as string)

```
Born = DateTime.Parse(bornDate);
```